# BluetoothSocket not connecting to target device

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, kotlin

I'm trying to connect my device to another one via Bluetooth, but when I select the device I want to connect with, I get an `IOException` saying

> read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Just to illustrate how my app works, I have a `RecyclerView` populated with the devices my Bluetooth scan has found, then when I click an item the app is supposed to connect with that device.

Below is my the code for my connection thread:

```
private val MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")

private lateinit var device: BluetoothDevice
private lateinit var onDeviceActionListener: OnDeviceActionListener
private lateinit var socket: BluetoothSocket

fun init(device: BluetoothDevice,
         onDeviceActionListener: OnDeviceActionListener): ConnectionThread {
    this.device = device
    this.onDeviceActionListener = onDeviceActionListener
    try {
        socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating socket", e)
    }
    return this
}

override fun run() {
    try {
        socket.connect()
    } catch (openException: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error opening connection. Trying to close...", openException)
        try {
            socket.close()
        } catch (closeException: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error closing socket", closeException)
        }
        return
    }
    onDeviceActionListener.onDeviceConnect(device)
}
```

My guess is there is something wrong with my UUID. I've tried some other values but still didn't work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: No idea if capitalization of the UUID might make a difference? Value looks ok otherwise (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery)

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't see exactly what you are doing wrong here. However, I have done quite a bit of Bluetooth work. More recently just focused in BLE. You should be able to discover your nearby BT devices and see their UUIDs.

I have written a helper class about 3 years ago so it's a little old, but should be mostly the same code. Happy to share it with you if it helps.

```
public class BluetoothConnector {

private static final String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + BluetoothConnector.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String DEFAULT_SERVER_NAME_FOR_APP = "tn_bt_default_server";
private static final int DEFAULT_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION_MS = 30000;
private static final UUID DEFAULT_UUID = UUID.fromString("6534c201-039c-4e4f-89f9-5ca8cfeb9667");
public static final int ENABLE_DISCOVER_INTENT = 1002;

protected boolean mIsToastEnabled = false; //Access from calling class to enable toasting of progress to screen if necessary
private Handler mUIHandler;
private static ServerSocketThread mServerSocketThread;
private static ClientSocketThread mClientSocketThread;
private ManageConnectionThread mManageConnectionThread;
private Context mContext;
private IBluetoothDataListener mBluetoothDataListener;
public final Object ServerSocketLock = new Object();
public final Object ClientSocketLock = new Object();
public final Object ManageConnectionLock = new Object();



public BluetoothConnector(Context context, IBluetoothDataListener listener){
    this(context, new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()), listener);

}
public BluetoothConnector(Context context, Handler UIHandler, IBluetoothDataListener listener){
    Log.v(TAG, "BluetoothConnector(context=" + context + ", Handler=" + UIHandler.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", IBluetoothDataListener=" + listener.getClass().getSimpleName());
    mContext = context;
    mUIHandler = UIHandler;
    mBluetoothDataListener = listener;

}


public void makeThisDeviceDiscoverable(Activity callingActivity){
    makeThisDeviceDiscoverable(callingActivity, BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(), DEFAULT_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION_MS);

}
public void makeThisDeviceDiscoverable(Activity callingActivity, BluetoothAdapter adapter){
    makeThisDeviceDiscoverable(callingActivity, adapter, DEFAULT_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION_MS);

}
public void makeThisDeviceDiscoverable(Activity callingActivity, int durationInMs){
    makeThisDeviceDiscoverable(callingActivity, BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(), durationInMs);

}
public void makeThisDeviceDiscoverable(Activity callingActivity, BluetoothAdapter adapter, int durationInMs) {
    Log.v(TAG, "makeThisDeviceDiscoverable(callingActivity=" + callingActivity.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", BluetoothAdapter=" + (adapter == null ? "null" : adapter.getName()) + ", duration=" + String.valueOf(durationInMs));
    if(adapter == null){
        Log.v(TAG, "adapter is null");

    }else if(adapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Launching Activity to request Discoverable Permission");
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, durationInMs);
        callingActivity.startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, ENABLE_DISCOVER_INTENT);

    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "adapter is already in SCAN MODE");

    }

}
public void awaitConnectionFromDevice(){
    awaitConnectionFromDevice(DEFAULT_UUID, BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());

}
public void awaitConnectionFromDevice(UUID commonKey){
    awaitConnectionFromDevice(commonKey, BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());

}
public void awaitConnectionFromDevice(BluetoothAdapter adapter){
    awaitConnectionFromDevice(DEFAULT_UUID, adapter);

}
public void awaitConnectionFromDevice(UUID commonKey, BluetoothAdapter adapter){
    Log.v(TAG, "awaitConnectionFromDevice for UUID: " + String.valueOf(commonKey) + ", BluetoothAdapter=" + (adapter == null ? "null" : adapter.getName()));
    cancelDiscovery();

    synchronized (ServerSocketLock){
        if(mServerSocketThread != null){
            Log.v(TAG, "Server Socket Thread was not null so canceling current Thread");
            mServerSocketThread.cancel();

        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Attempting to Start new ServerThread");
        mServerSocketThread = new ServerSocketThread(commonKey, adapter);
        mServerSocketThread.start();

    }

}
public void cancelAwaitingConnectionFromDevice(){
    Log.v(TAG, "cancelAwaitingConnectionFromDevice");
    synchronized (ServerSocketLock){
        if(mServerSocketThread != null){
            mServerSocketThread.cancel();
            mServerSocketThread = null;
            Log.v(TAG, "canceling Server Socket Thread");

        }else{
            Log.v(TAG, "Server Socket null, so not canceling");

        }

    }

}

public void startDiscovery() {
    startDiscovery(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());

}
public void startDiscovery(BluetoothAdapter adapter){
    Log.v(TAG, "startDiscovery to find list of devices in range");
    adapter.startDiscovery();

}
public void cancelDiscovery() {
    cancelDiscovery(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());

}
public void cancelDiscovery(BluetoothAdapter adapter){
    Log.v(TAG, "cancelDiscovery");
    adapter.cancelDiscovery();

}
public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device){
    connectToDevice(device, DEFAULT_UUID);

}
public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device, UUID commonKey){
    Log.v(TAG, "connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice=" + (device == null ? "null" : device.getName()) + ", UUID=" + String.valueOf(commonKey));
    synchronized (ClientSocketLock){
        if(mClientSocketThread != null){
            Log.v(TAG, "Client Socket Thread was not null so canceling current Thread");
            mClientSocketThread.cancel();

        }else{
            Log.v(TAG, "Client Socket Thread is NULL so not canceling");

        }

        Log.v(TAG, "ClientSocketThread Starting");
        mClientSocketThread = new ClientSocketThread(device, commonKey);
        mClientSocketThread.start();

    }

}
public BluetoothDevice getBluetoothDeviceByMac(String mac){
    Log.v(TAG, "getBluetoothDeviceByMac(mac=" + mac);
    return getBluetoothDeviceByMac(mac, BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());

}
public BluetoothDevice getBluetoothDeviceByMac(String mac, BluetoothAdapter adapter) {
    Log.v(TAG, "getBluetoothDeviceByMac(mac=" + mac + ", BluetoothAdapter=" + (adapter == null ? "null" : adapter.getName()));
    return adapter.getRemoteDevice(mac);

}

public ArrayList<KeyValueModel> getPairedDevices(){
    return getPairedDevices(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());
}
public ArrayList<KeyValueModel> getPairedDevices(BluetoothAdapter adapter){
    ArrayList<KeyValueModel> bondedDevices = new ArrayList<KeyValueModel>();

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
    Log.v(TAG, "getPairedDevices Found " + pairedDevices.size() + " number of paired devices");

    // If there are paired devices
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        // Loop through paired devices
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            bondedDevices.add(new KeyValueModel(device.getAddress(), device.getName()));

        }
    }

    return bondedDevices;
}
public static void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device){
    Log.v(TAG, "unpairDevice");
    try{
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
        method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error Unpairing Device: " + ex.getMessage());

    }
}
public boolean sendDataToConnectedDevice(byte[] data){
    Log.v(TAG, "sendDataToConnectedDevice");
    synchronized (ManageConnectionLock){
        mManageConnectionThread.write(data);
        return true;

    }

}
public void setBluetoothDataListener(IBluetoothDataListener listener){
    mBluetoothDataListener = listener;
}
public boolean getIsConnected(){
    synchronized (ManageConnectionLock) {
        return mManageConnectionThread != null && mManageConnectionThread.isAlive();

    }
}

private void startManageConnectionThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
    Log.v(TAG, "startManageConnectionThread for Socket: " + (socket == null ? "null" : socket.getClass().getSimpleName()));
    synchronized (ManageConnectionLock) {
        mManageConnectionThread = new ManageConnectionThread(socket);
        mManageConnectionThread.start();

    }

}
private void handleDataReceivedFromConnectedDevice(final byte[] bytes){
    Log.v(TAG, "handleDataReceivedFromConnectedDevice");
    Log.v(TAG, "bytes to Listener: " + new String(bytes));

    if(mUIHandler != null && mBluetoothDataListener != null){
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mBluetoothDataListener != null) {
                    mBluetoothDataListener.onReceivedPayloadFromConnectedDevice(bytes);

                }

            }

        });

    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "UIHandler was null so skipped sending payload to listener");

    }

}
private void handleConnected(){
    Log.e(TAG, "handleConnected");
    if(mUIHandler != null && mBluetoothDataListener != null){
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mBluetoothDataListener != null){
                    mBluetoothDataListener.onConnectedToTargetDevice();

                }

            }

        });

    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "UIHandler was null so skipped sending payload to listener");

    }

}
private void handleDisconnected(){
    Log.e(TAG, "handleDisconnected");
    if(mUIHandler != null && mBluetoothDataListener != null){
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mBluetoothDataListener != null){
                    mBluetoothDataListener.onDisconnectedFromTargetDevice();

                }
            }
        });

    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "UIHandler or Listener was null so skipped sending payload to listener");

    }
}
private void handleFailedToConnectAsServer(final Exception ex){
    Log.e(TAG, "handleFailedToConnectAsServer ex:  " + ex.getMessage());
    if(mUIHandler != null && mBluetoothDataListener != null){
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mBluetoothDataListener != null){
                    mBluetoothDataListener.onFailedToReceiveConnectionFromTargetDevice(ex);

                }
            }
        });

    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "UIHandler or Listener was null so skipped sending payload to listener");

    }

}
private void handleFailedToConnectAsClient(final Exception ex){
    Log.e(TAG, "handleFailedToConnectAsClient ex:  " + ex.getMessage());
    if(mUIHandler != null && mBluetoothDataListener != null){
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mBluetoothDataListener != null){
                    mBluetoothDataListener.onFailedToConnectToTargetDevice(ex);

                }
            }
        });

    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "UIHandler or Listener was null so skipped sending payload to listener");

    }
}
private void handleErrorInRetrievingData(final Exception ex){
    Log.e(TAG, "handleErrorInRetrievingData ex:  " + ex.getMessage());
    if(mUIHandler != null && mBluetoothDataListener != null){
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mBluetoothDataListener != null){
                    mBluetoothDataListener.onErrorReceivingPayloadFromConnectedDevice(ex);

                }

            }
        });

    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "UIHandler or Listener was null so skipped sending payload to listener");

    }

}
private void handleFailedToSendDataToConnectedDevice(final Exception ex){
    Log.e(TAG, "handleFailedToSendDataToConnectedDevice ex:  " + ex.getMessage());
    if(mUIHandler != null && mBluetoothDataListener != null){
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mBluetoothDataListener != null){
                    mBluetoothDataListener.onFailedToSendDataToConnectedDevice(ex);

                }

            }
        });

    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "UIHandler or Listener was null so skipped sending payload to listener");

    }

}
private void toastMessage(final String value){
    if(!mIsToastEnabled || mUIHandler == null) {
        return;
    }

    mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Toast.makeText(mContext, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.v(TAG, "Error Toasting, possibly bad handler, or context: " + ex.getMessage());

            }
        }
    });
}


private class ServerSocketThread extends Thread{

    private final String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + ServerSocketThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mServerSocket;

    public ServerSocketThread(UUID commonKey, BluetoothAdapter adapter) {
        Log.v(TAG, "ServerSocketThread Constructor");
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "listening for RFComas Server: " + DEFAULT_SERVER_NAME_FOR_APP + ", and commonKey: " + String.valueOf(commonKey));
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(DEFAULT_SERVER_NAME_FOR_APP, commonKey);
            toastMessage("Listening for RFComm As Server on UUID: " + String.valueOf(commonKey));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating ServerSocket: " + e.getMessage());
            toastMessage("Error Creating ServerSocket: " + e.getMessage());

        }

        mServerSocket = tmp;

    }

    public void run() {
        Log.v(TAG, "ServerSocket run");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (mServerSocket != null) {
            try {
                Log.v(TAG, "ServerSocket.accept()");
                toastMessage("ServerSocket.accept()");
                //Waits for Client Connection to pass Socket, then we close down
                socket = mServerSocket.accept();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ServerSocket.accept() Error: " + e.getMessage());
                toastMessage("ServerSocket.accept() Error: " + e.getMessage());
                handleFailedToConnectAsServer(e);
                break;

            }

            // If a connection was accepted we don't need to keep server listening, so close unless multiple client/server connections is desired
            if (socket != null) {
                try{
                    Log.v(TAG, "ServerSocket Accepted Client Socket, Begin Listening Connect Thread");
                    toastMessage("ServerSocket Accepted Client Socket, Begin Listening Connect Thread");
                    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                    startManageConnectionThread(socket);
                    //mServerSocket.close();

                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception closing Server Socket");

                }

                //break; //Add in Break if you want to shut down listening for connections
            }else{
                Log.v(TAG, "Socket wasn't accepted");
                toastMessage("Socket wasn't accepted");
                handleFailedToConnectAsServer(new Exception("Socket is Null"));

            }
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Exiting Server Accept Thread");
    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "ServerSocketThread Canceled");
            mServerSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ServerSocketThread Error: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }

}
private class ClientSocketThread extends Thread{

    private BluetoothSocket mSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    public ClientSocketThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID commonKey) {
        Log.v(TAG, "ClientSocketThread Constructor");
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "Client creating RFComm Socket to Server with UUID: " + String.valueOf(commonKey));
            toastMessage("Client creating RFComm Socket to Server with UUID: " + String.valueOf(commonKey));
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(commonKey);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating Client Socket: " + e.getMessage());
            toastMessage("Creating Socket Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            handleFailedToConnectAsClient(e);

        }

        mSocket = tmp;

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            if(mSocket == null){
                Log.e(TAG, "Error Client Socket is Null, Canceling Client Thread");
                return;

            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Client Connecting");
            // Connect to the server, or timeout eventually
            toastMessage("Client Connecting");
            mSocket.connect();

        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and try the fallback method of reflection with port to connect
            try {
                Log.e("", "trying fallback...");
                toastMessage("Client Connection Failed Exception: " + connectException.getMessage());

                mSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mDevice, 1);
                toastMessage("Client Connect Again Attempt 2, but with fall back Reflection and port");
                Log.v(TAG, "Client Connect Again Attempt 2, but with fall back Reflection and port");
                mSocket.connect();

                Log.e("", "Connected");
                toastMessage("Client Connected");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("", "Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection!");
                toastMessage("Client Couldn't Establish Connection to Server: " + ex.getMessage());
                handleFailedToConnectAsClient(ex);
                return;

            }
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        startManageConnectionThread(mSocket);
    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "Client Socket cancel");
            mSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error Closing Socket");

        }
    }

}
private class ManageConnectionThread extends Thread {

    /////////////
    // MEMBERS //
    /////////////
    private final String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + ManageConnectionThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private final BluetoothSocket mSocket;
    private final InputStream mInStream;
    private final OutputStream mOutStream;


    //////////////////
    //  CONSTRUCTOR //
    //////////////////
    public ManageConnectionThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mSocket = socket;

        handleConnected();
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "ManageConnectionThread Constructor");
            Log.v(TAG, "Connected to Socket = " + String.valueOf(socket.isConnected()));
            toastMessage("Listening for input or output Stream");
            Log.v(TAG, "Get InputStream");
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            Log.v(TAG, "Get OutputStream");
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting Socket Streams: " + e.getMessage());
            toastMessage("Connect Thread: Error: " + e.getMessage());
            handleErrorInRetrievingData(e);

        }

        mInStream = tmpIn;
        mOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    ///////////////
    // OVERRIDES //
    ///////////////
    public void run() {
        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                byte[] data = new byte[16384];
                int nRead;
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                while ((nRead = mInStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                    //Log.v(TAG, "bytes Read: " + String.valueOf(nRead));
                    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);

                    //TODO Find better way to find End Of Message rather than looking for }
                    String temp = new String(buffer.toByteArray());
                    //Log.v(TAG, "current Data: " + temp);
                    if(temp.contains("}")){
                        Log.v(TAG, "bytes reading complete");
                        handleDataReceivedFromConnectedDevice(buffer.toByteArray());
                        buffer.flush();
                        buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    }else{
                        Log.v(TAG, "More bytes Available");

                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading inputStream");
                handleErrorInRetrievingData(e);
                break;

            }

        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Exiting Managed Connection Thread");
        handleDisconnected();

    }


    /////////////
    // METHODS //
    /////////////
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "ManageConnectionThread write(bytes)");
            mOutStream.write(bytes);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error Writing Stream: " + e.getMessage());
            handleFailedToSendDataToConnectedDevice(e);

        }
    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "ManageConnectionThread cancel");
            handleDisconnected();
            mSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error Closing BluetoothSocket: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }

}


public interface IBluetoothDataListener{

    //////////////////////
    // OVERRIDE METHODS //
    //////////////////////
    void onReceivedPayloadFromConnectedDevice(byte[] payload);
    void onErrorReceivingPayloadFromConnectedDevice(Exception ex);
    void onFailedToConnectToTargetDevice(Exception ex);
    void onFailedToReceiveConnectionFromTargetDevice(Exception ex);
    void onFailedToSendDataToConnectedDevice(Exception ex);
    void onConnectedToTargetDevice();
    void onDisconnectedFromTargetDevice();

}
```

}

Then of course you will want to make sure you have your broadcast receivers setup:

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.BluetoothChangedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.DISAPPEARED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.BluetoothDeviceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.DISAPPEARED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Originally had nice javadocs and headers, but Stack Overflow limits character count so had to remove them to make it fit lol. Hope it helps, if not, no worries, good luck all the same.

Comment: Thank you for your help mate!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: hello Sam
What is BluetoothChangedReceiver and  BluetoothDeviceReceiver?

Comment: hi Bipin, this post is so old, I'm not even sure where I kept these files anymore lol. but they were just standard receiver classes named as you see above and then they would forward bluetooth connection events to whoever was listening for it in the app. I'll see if I can find them, but at this point, there is probably newer libraries to help with all of this stuff.

Comment: @BipinBharti were did you get the list of all unpaired devices ?