# Get list of unpaired devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I write code for scanning unpaired Bluetooth devices ... I have tried many websites to scan but it is not scanning for devices ...

Its a code of Scan_Button and below this ... a Broadcaster which we use to register a found device ...

```
    btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                IntentFilter discoverDeviceIntent = new IntentFilter(ACTION_FOUND);
                registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, discoverDeviceIntent);
            }
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                IntentFilter discoverDeviceIntent = new IntentFilter(ACTION_FOUND);
                registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, discoverDeviceIntent);


            }

        }
    });

    mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(ACTION_FOUND)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                final ArrayAdapter BtArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                BtArrayAdapter.add(device.getName());
                BtArrayAdapter.add(device.getAddress());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Showing Unpaired Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                unpairlv.setAdapter(BtArrayAdapter);

            }
        }
    };
```

I got two permissions in Manifest file ...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: In which android version are you testing? if >= android 6.0 then u need `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` permission as well

Comment: android 3.0 beta 4

Comment: I asked for Android OS version (like Marshmallow or lollipop) of device, not of Android Studio :)

Comment: oh sorry ... 6.0.1 ...

Comment: Did you added `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` permission in Manifest? Also you'll need to ask that permission runtime or for testing, just enable that permission from settings>apps>YourApp>permissions & see if you get the scan results

Comment: No i didnt add this permission ... let me try to add this .. if it works ...

Comment: No its not work after adding this permission

Comment: did you enabled permission manually?

Comment: i just added in the Manifest ...

Comment: From Android 6.0, you need Location permission as well for scanning devices & you'll need to get the permission explicitly runtime from 6.0. Declaring in manfiest won't grant you permission. Please search for runtime permission in android or just enable that permission manually from settings for now for testing purpose

Comment: thank you so much for helping me .. i added run time permissions and now i have list unpaired devices but in this list it shows paired devices too ...

Answer (score 0):

I've answered something similar in another question, but here is an example class that will do everything you need.

[BluetoothSocket not connecting to target device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289221/bluetoothsocket-not-connecting-to-target-device/46290020?noredirect=1#comment79543495_46290020)

It will let you make yourself discoverable, connect, search around you for BT devices and manage reading/writing etc.. It can get pretty convoluted so if I can jump start you with this class, I recommend you take it and tweak it for your needs it will save you a ton of time.

Goodluck.