# Bluetooth Connected but doesnt actually connects

Tags: android, bluetooth

Im doing a bluetooth oriented app, that connects only to our bluetooth devices, everything works fine if I connect the bluetooth device using the android way, AKA Going to Config > bluetooth > pair > enable.

But we need the user to keep inside the app, for that I managed to get the device and pair it to the phone but when I call the socket.connect(); the device reacts and tells that its connected to the phone, but the phone shows the device paired but not active.

this is my code. (all on the same thread for testing)

```
     if ((device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)) {

                                 BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

                                try {
                                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                                    mmSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                                    try {
                                        mmSocket.connect();

                                        mostrarToast("Dispositivo ANDA conectado satisfactoriamente");
                                    } catch (IOException connectException) {
                                        try {
                                            mostrarToast("Dispositivo ANDA no conectado");
                                            mmSocket.close();
                                        } catch (IOException closeException) {
                                            closeException.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        return;
                                    }


                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "but not the other way around" ?

Comment: The phone shows the device paired but not active.

Comment: Hi Luis, paired and active are two different things. Paired should enable you to communicate to it. So it depends on what type of communication you are attempting to do (bytes for embedded comm, or music, or voice) etc.. Take a look at my answer to this post, maybe the helper class will find something you overlooked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289221/bluetoothsocket-not-connecting-to-target-device/46290020?noredirect=1#comment79543495_46290020

Comment: Im trying to get the phone to mark the device as active so I can send the audio as it normally does with the android UI, I have been looking on a lot of questions regarding this but cant really find the answer I need. I will look up, if not i will just put the bluetooth config activity, there's no more time left. I really appreciate your code, thank you